# Extract mdf & ldf files from backup file?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

Is there a way to extract SQL Server files (.mdf & .ldf) from a backup file (.bak) to a physical location, without `restore database`?

I need a restore query or script to restore files from bak file only, no attaching to server.
Please don't speak about detaching query after restore.

Comment: Not possible I'm afraid. If you can explain why you want to do this, we may have other suggestions that could help.

Comment: I have many customers and sometimes they give me backup for fix some issue. I want to restore their backup as ms sql files and use them in local file without attaching to sql server (connection runtime attaching)

Comment: If you know how to 'use' an MDF w/o attaching it to a runtime SQL Server then I'm confident you know perfectly well how to extract an MDF from a BAK...

Comment: When you use runtime attaching of a database, it still must be attached to an instance of SQL Server.  Are you connecting to a remote instance of SQL?  Are you working with a local instance of SQL Express?  Are you using a local SQL Express User Instance?  Do you have access to the source code for the utility to work with the MDF and LDF files?

Comment: Real men run queries in a hex editor!

Comment: With third party tools, you can get the information w/o restoring the database to a usable state, but you still need a running instance of SQL Server. Unless of course, you take @Andomar advice.

Answer (score 5):

ApexSQL has recently released a tool that can do this. It's [ApexSQL Restore](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_restore.aspx). I haven't tested it fully yet, but you have to connect to a SQL Server instance to do this. It attaches database backup file and creates MDF and LDF files for the database.

Comment: ApexSQL Restore is no longer supported available !!

Answer (score 4):

RedGate software has a product called [SQL Virtual Restore](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/) which will allow you to attach the backup file to an instance without restoring it and get out the information that you need.  This is your only option without using a hex editor.

Comment: SQL Virtual Restore has been discontinued !!

Answer (score -3):

If you have a .bak file, and all you want is to restore that file to a mdf. Then this is what you can do. It's a little hacky but works.

First you need an empty .mdf and .ldf files. The easier way to do that is to create a Web Project in Visual Studio and then In the App_Data folder right click and add new database. That will create an mdf and a .ldf.

Now copy those files to the data directory of your SQLSERVER Express. If it usually under the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server. In my case it is in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\

So if your database is PhoneBook just copy:

`copy PhoneBook.mdf “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\PhoneBook.mdf” 
copy PhoneBook_log.ldf “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\PhoneBook_log.ldf”`

Now attach your database:

open a Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt or other prompt (Remember to right click the Run as Administrator, specially if it is Vista)

in the command prompt run:

`sqlcmd –S ./SQLEXPRESS`

and run the following commands:

`CREATE DATABASE Phonebook ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\Phonebook.mdf' ), 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\Phonebook_log.ldf' ) 
FOR ATTACH ; 
GO`

copy your .BAK file to the data directory.

`copy PhoneBook.bak “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\PhoneBook.bak”`
NOTE: Why the data directory: It seems that in some installation you can have permission issues

`RESTORE DATABASE PhoneBook 
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\PhoneBook2.BAK' 
WITH MOVE 'Phonebook' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\Phonebook.mdf', 
MOVE 'Phonebook_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\Phonebook_log.ldf', 
REPLACE`

After that if everything runs ok then you can detach your database:

1> `exec sp_detach_db 'Phonebook'`

Now you can copy your mdf files back to where you wanted them

NOTE: If you don't know the name you have to put for Data and Log then Run commands like

`RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK ='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\PhoneBook2.BAK'

RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK ='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\PhoneBook2.BAK'`

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to the site. I wonder how this answer solves the `without restore database` and  `no attaching to server. Please don't speak about detaching query after restore.` parts?